# Specify number of cores for R doParallel

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I'm trying to specify a parallel process in R to use 3 out of 4 possible cores on my computer to leave a bit of CPU power for other processes while this runs in the background. My code looks something like this:

```
library(doParallel)

cl <- makePSOCKcluster(3)
registerDoParallel(cl)

results <- foreach(i = 1:10) %dopar% {
...some processes to be parallelized...
}

stopCluster(cl)
```

When I run this and look in task manager, all cores are running at 100%. Is there a way to only use 3 cores, or is this not possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Running your code with `c <- 0; while(c < 1e8) c <- c + 1` in the middle uses only 3 cores for me.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure this has been answered elsewhere, but ...

```
cl <- makePSOCKcluster(detectCores() * .875)
```

OR

```
cl <- makePSOCKcluster(detectCores() - 1)
```

Will work for this.

Check out the help page on `detectCores()` and one final warning is that I once put detectCores inside of a loop thinking its fast ... its not, so if you need it more than a few times, assign a variable.

Finally, I very much favor parallelization using furrr (future_map, etc.) instead of foreach() %dopar% these days.

Comment: This is not really answering the question as the OP is already trying to use 3 cores out of 4.

Comment: Any detail why you prefer furrr?

Answer (score 0):

Using `mcaffinity` before running parallel process, you can limit the number of cores.

```
parallel::mcaffinity(1:3)
```

This `mcaffinity` allow your R work to allocate only the first 3 cores.